# Gradle - Generate source and compile

Tags: maven, gradle, code-generation, processor

I'm migrating from Maven to Gradle and I have an issue with generated sources. Here's the `build.gradle` of one of the subprojects

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'net.ltgt.apt-idea' version '0.15'
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compileOnly 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:jpa'
    compileOnly 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:1.3.0.Final'
}

def generatedSources = "${buildDir}/generated/source/apt/main"
def generatedOutputDir = file("$generatedSources")

task generateSources(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build') {
    doFirst {
        generatedOutputDir.exists() || generatedOutputDir.mkdirs()
        sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["${generatedSources}", 'src/main/java']
    }
    options.compilerArgs += [
            '-processor', '-proc:none',
            'org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor,' +
                    'com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor',
            '-AaddSuppressWarningsAnnotation=true',
            '-Aquerydsl.entityAccessors=true',
            '-s', "${generatedSources}"
    ]
}

compileJava.finalizedBy generateSources
```

The classes are generated correctly, but right after the generation I receive the error "no suitable method found for..."

Basically the compilation fails because the generated classes are not taken into account during the compilation phase.

With the `finalizedBy` I was pretty sure it would work, but no..

Any ideas on how else I can get the class generation to run before the `compileJava` phase?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
compileJava.finalizedBy generateSources
```

Should be

```
compileJava.dependsOn generateSources
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks